# MySQL - Trying to Combine 3 SELECTS into one

Tags: mysql, select

I need to run the following 3 Select Queries:

```
SELECT profile_gender AS Gender, COUNT(*) AS Users FROM login GROUP BY profile_gender;

SELECT profile_gender AS Gender, COUNT(*) AS Users FROM login WHERE profile_createdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY profile_gender;

SELECT profile_gender AS Gender, COUNT(*) AS Users FROM login WHERE profile_createdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY profile_gender;
```

The profile_gender is either 0 or 1 and resides in the same Column. Is it possible to get this information in one query? Its a bit beyond my currently querying ability.

thanks

Comment: You can always use `UNION`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT profile_gender AS Gender, COUNT(*) AS Users,
       sum(profile_createdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as cnt_1day,
       sum(profile_createdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) as cnt_7day
FROM login
GROUP BY profile_gender;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do the counting in the actual field list:

```
SELECT profile_gender AS Gender,
    SUM(profile_createdate > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Day1,
    SUM(profile_createdate > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AS Day7,
    COUNT(profile_createdate) AS Total
FROM login
GROUP BY profile_gender
```

The boolean results of the `>` comparisons will get typecast to plain integer `0` or `1` by mysql, which can then be `SUM()`ed.